# Making an element optional in dtd

Tags: xml, dtd

If an element is declared like below in the dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT cite.query (#PCDATA|cite.query | citator.treatment>
```

I get an error saying `cite.query` must have `citator.treatment` then how do I make it optional for `cite.query` to have a `citator.treatment`?

Comment: Really?  I would expect any self-respecting XML parser to reject the ill-formed declaration instead of trying to validate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the content model of `cite.query` is mixed (both #PCDATA and elements), you'll need to use an asterisk outside of the group:

```
<!ELEMENT cite.query (#PCDATA|cite.query|citator.treatment)*>
```